# How do I resolve the error that occurred when migrating a windows local reactjs application to Linux?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to migrate on linux centos8 an application in reactjs that runs well locally in w10 with localhost:3000 for react and localhost:3001 for nodejs.

I created in /home a folder for node in which I copied everything in the local node folder, except node_modules, I ran there npm install, I launched nodejs with the command node index.js, I tested some endpoints from postman, everything it's ok on the node side.

I created in /home a folder for the reactjs application, I copied everything in the local react folder except node_modules, I gave npm install, node_modules was created.
Then I give the command: npm start and get the error:

Failed to compile.

./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
Error: No valid exports main found for '/home/parcare-react-test/node_modules/colorette'

and the reacjs does not start.
What can I do?
Thanks,

Comment: did the `npm install` command on the react app throw any errors? It appears that one of your dependencies is missing, I'd try deleting the react node_modules folder and running the install again. If all goes well, compare your linux and windows packahe.json files to see if there's any difference, and make sure you've saved all the installed modules to your package.json file. Or you can start by running `npm i -S colorette` inside your react folder and see if that alone fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does `/home/paracre-react-test/node_modules/colorette` exist?

My hunch is that it's installed *globally* (outside the project) on the original machine.

Run `npm ls -g colorette` to see if that package is installed globally, and `npm ls colorette` from the app directory to see if it's installed locally.

If it's global on the original machine, you can install it on the destination machine with `npm i -g colorette` (or whatever the parent package name is if it's a dependency of something else.)

If that's the issue and you don't want to install it globally on the destination machine, just install it into the app dir with `npm i -D colorette`. (I'm assuming it's a [devDependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file). If I'm wrong about that omit the `-D`.)